# Change binary tree's elements with a given array while protecting tree structure

Tags: java, tree, structure, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

In java, I have a binary tree. And I want to change it's elements from elements in a given array. But I must protect the structure. After that, I should convert it to binary search tree.

How can I change binary tree's elements with elements in a given array, without destroying structure?

What I mean is in the picture below.

[image: bt to bst]

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort the array
2. Perform an inorder traversal of the tree
3. Populate the nodes in that order with the sorted values